# when i am trying to render my cup and plate why is donut rendering too?

Tags: rendering

I am following blender guru donut tutorial and I am making coffee cup but when I am rendering the cup and plate it's rendering donut too , though I hide the donut but still it's not solved. What should I do now , kindly help. I am could not able to find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders. The best solution is to make a new collection and add your object to it, then disable (not hide) the collection.

[image: HiddenCollection]

Comment: okay, thankyou so much @christopherbennett . That really helped.

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @tanyagarg How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You could follow Christopher's solution or what I usually do is select my object that needs to be disabled in the render, go to the **outliner** and press the camera icon right next to the eye icon so that an **'X'** mark appears in the middle of it, this means that your object is **temporarily** disabled, as in hidden, in your renders but **not** in the viewport. If you want it to be hidden in the viewport too simply click on the eye icon.

[image]

[image]

**HOW TO HIDE AN OBJECT IN THE VIEWPORT**

[image]

Comment: okay, thank you so much @ribbit12 for your suggestion.